# How can I turn off rounding in Spark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rounding

I have a dataframe and I'm doing this:

```
df = dataframe.withColumn("test", lit(0.4219759403))
```

I want to get just the first four numbers after the dot, without rounding.

When I cast to DecimalType, with `.cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(20,4)`
or even with `round` function, this number is rounded to `0.4220`.

The only way that I found without rounding is applying the function `format_number()`, but this function gives me a string, and when I cast this `string to DecimalType(20,4)`, the framework rounds the number again to `0.4220`.

I need to convert this number to `DecimalType(20,4)` without rounding, and I expect to see `0.4219`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have numbers with more than 1 digit before the decimal point, the `substr` is not adapt. Instead, you can use a regex to **always** extract the first 4 decimal digits (if present).
You can do this using [`regexp_extract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html)

```
df = dataframe.withColumn('rounded', F.regexp_extract(F.col('test'), '\d+\.\d{0,4}', 0))
```

---

Example

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dataframe = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0.4219759403, ),
    (0.4, ),
    (1.0, ),
    (0.5431293, ),
    (123.769859, )
], ['test'])
df = dataframe.withColumn('rounded', F.regexp_extract(F.col('test'), '\d+\.\d{0,4}', 0))
df.show()

+------------+--------+
|        test| rounded|
+------------+--------+
|0.4219759403|  0.4219|
|         0.4|     0.4|
|         1.0|     1.0|
|   0.5431293|  0.5431|
|  123.769859|123.7698|
+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi welcome to stackoverflow,
please next time try to provide a reproducible example with the code you tried, anyways this works for me:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c"),
], ["ID", "Text"])

df = df.withColumn("test", lit(0.4219759403))
df = df.withColumn("test_string", F.substring(df["test"].cast("string"), 0, 6))
df = df.withColumn("test_string_decimaltype", df["test_string"].cast(DecimalType(20,4)))
df.show()
df.printSchema()

+---+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| ID|Text|        test|test_string|test_string_decimaltype|
+---+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  1|   a|0.4219759403|     0.4219|                 0.4219|
|  2|   b|0.4219759403|     0.4219|                 0.4219|
|  3|   c|0.4219759403|     0.4219|                 0.4219|
+---+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+

root
 |-- ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: double (nullable = false)
 |-- test_string: string (nullable = false)
 |-- test_string_decimaltype: decimal(20,4) (nullable = true)
```

Of course if you want you can overwrite the same column by putting always "test", i choose different names to let you see the steps.